# Grammar question for this phrase, "The movie deserves better than what it got at the box office", specifically the "got" part

Tags: grammar

I'm currently trying to help my non-English friends with some of their English grammar questions. This specific phrase,

> The movie deserves better than what it got at the box office.

Specifically the "got" part is difficult to explain. Is there a grammar explanation that can explain the usage of "got" here?

Comment: Besides the basic definition of gathered, received, earned?

Answer (score 1):

A rewrite of the sentence that maintains its meaning is:

> The movie should have received more money in box office sales than it actually received

"Received" is replacing "got" here, and is a transitive verb, with the direct object being the amount of money it deserved.

Another rewrite that might be useful is:

> The movie **received** less **money** than the amount of money it deserved.

A sentence with only the subject, verb, and direct object would be:

> The movie received money

With "received" still functioning in the same way that "got" did in the original.

Comment: The movie made more money at the box office. Movies don't receive money....

Comment: Right, both of you. _Get_ means _receive_ here, but specifically, with movies, the phrase used is _make money_ instead of _receive money_. _Receive_ is a pretty formal verb, but _get_ can stand in for most of its senses.